# transactional saves list after pushing messages to queue

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I have a function with .

```
@Transactional
posting method(list<A>){

It get a list as arguments. list <A> listA.

//I update status in complete list. and then save it .

aJpaRepo.save(listA);

//traverse listA and get B out of each A object, update B and save it

bJpaRepo.save(listB);

// now i am traversing listA and sending each object to a message queue for system C.
Cgateway.send(a);

logger.info("print message");

}
```

there is a handler resHandler which recieves response from C system and updates listA and list B based on that response.

Now issue is, some times above mentioned method throws exception due to optimistic locking. I notice it is because at those scenerios list of items is big enough that this posting method is yet to save it completely  and resHandler got the response from system C and tries to update the row with the response.

Here i am getting this log "print message" printed before getting exception logs.

Here, i am saving list A and list B before sending messages on gateway of system C. yet this situation is happening. Is it because of transactional. Is it saving it after pushing messages to gateway.